Why recreated ssh-keygen files under root subdirectory?
On kubuntu 22.04 I reinstalled ssh-keygen :
 sudo ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/root/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:Q40/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX root@master-at-home
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 3072]----+
|... ..           |
|oo.+o..  o       |
|.+.o=o+ = .      |
|  oo.o.= B       |
|   .. .oS B      |
|     o=.o. +     |
|    .E.+  o      |
|     .*+ . .     |
|    .o*B*o.      |

But files were generated under /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, but not under /home/master/.ssh, where master is current user.
Not sure if I can move the files manually or to change my command in the console ?
EDITIVE INFO :
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/CurrenciesXM$ ls -la ~/.ssh
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 жов 21 16:17 .
drwxr-x--- 31 master master 4096 жов 21 16:51 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root   2610 жов 29  2021 id_rsa
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    574 жов 29  2021 id_rsa.pub
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root   3556 жов 21 16:17 known_hosts
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root   3998 лис 22  2023 known_hosts.old
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/CurrenciesXM$ id
uid=1000(master) gid=1000(master) groups=1000(master),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),122(lpadmin),133(lxd),134(sambashare)
master@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/CurrenciesXM$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for master: 
root@master-at-home:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/CurrenciesXM# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),137(docker)


You should run ssh-keygen without sudo. If you get permission errors without sudo, you might have done something wrong before. Then, please, [edit] your question and show the output of the two commands ls -la ~/.ssh and id for user master.

Please read EDITIVE INFO

The command ssh-keygen should be run as normal user, not with root permissions.
The owner and group of the directory .ssh and the files in this directory are root:root. It should be master:master. That's why you will get errors when you run ssh-keygen as normal user.
Furthermore, the files have executable bits set, which is useless. The most critical point is that the private key file id_rsa is readable for everyone.
Probably you did something wrong in the past.
I suggest these commands to fix the ownership and permissions:
sudo chown -R master:master ~/.ssh
chmod -R o-rwx ~/.ssh
chmod -R og-w ~/.ssh
chmod og-r ~/.ssh/id_rsa
chmod a-x ~/.ssh/*

Explanation:

change ownership (This requires sudo, the following commands can be run as master.)
remove all access for others
remove write access for group (not necessary in this case)
remove read access for group and others from private key
remove executable bits from all files

If there were other private key files (id_* without .pub), the permissions for these should be the same as for id_rsa.
